Multiple Selections in the Drop-Down List Using VBA
I am having an issue with Multiple Selections in the Drop-Down List Using VBA i cant get it to work properly i am also trying to make the the list add up to numbers.
If I select multiple people it would add them example below
If selected DM,HK --> outcome would be 2
If selected DM, HK, IV --> Outcome would be 3
Please see the link below for the spread sheet i am working on
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/vdji8efr50xnoc4spbyb3/Salary-Staff-Qty-tracking.xlsx?rlkey=ln41iaeut12l36rsu9d6p3ff9&st=ava8uw74&dl=0
